# "Default" styles for RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-theme

I am writing an application that uses a RecyclerView to present a list of items. For each item it is possible to configure some settings. For that in turn I am using a PreferenceActivity, which extends [AppCompatPreferenceActivity](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary/blob/master/material_preferences_library/src/main/java/com/lb/material_preferences_library/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).

The settings in the PreferenceActivity are shown as a list, and have some default styles applied.

My question is, are these styles exposed somewhere, so that I can apply the same set of styles to my own RecyclerView, in order to have both screens (the list of items and the settings screen) look consistent?

Comment: you can search for recyclerview with multiple view holder

Answer (score 0):

here are the styles for [android.support.v7.preference](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/preference/res/values/styles.xml); and there are still the common `Preferences` (which were, in case I remember that correctly, partially if not merely deprecated). and meanwhile, those support v7 preferences might have been refactored towards [androidx.preference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/preference/res/values/styles.xml).